# Android Dynamic Gradient Drawing

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-bitmap, radial-gradients

Please see the image attached.

I would like to draw a gradient on the edges of the blue force field around the car, as seen in the image below.

The problem is that the gradient can appear on any edge of the blue square (depending on user input) and has to be oriented towards the center. In addition, it is also possible only small sections on the edge will have a gradient.

I have tried several different approaches and cannot get a decent solution.
Currently I am using a gradient defined in xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:type="radial" android:gradientRadius="75"
        android:startColor="@color/warningColor"
        android:endColor="#00d8345a"/>
</shape>
```

and then using it in java and drawing it using a bitmap on a `SurfaceView` canvas:

```
Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.circle_gradient, null);
mGradientBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(250, 250, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mGradientBmp);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
drawable.draw(canvas);
```

The input to the application is currently received through touch input where the user can touch anywhere on the screen. I am keeping a list of all touch points while `event.getAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` and draw the bitmap above in each of those locations, like so:

```
public void drawScreen(Canvas canvas) {

        long c = System.currentTimeMillis();
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.setMatrix(mPerspectiveMatrix);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mRoadBmp, 0,0, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mForceFieldBmp, null, mForceFieldRect, null);

        synchronized (mTouchPointsList) {
            for (PointF p : mTouchPointsList) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(mGradientBmp, p.x, p.y, null);
            }
        }
}
```

I have a couple of questions.

How would you suggest drawing the gradient (only around the edge of the blue force field) and keeping the gradient oriented towards the center?

How do I keep track of the touch points efficiently? I am currently using a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` because the input and drawing are on separate threads.

My current solution almost works (besides for being inefficient with the list so it slows down after a while) but the drawing needs to be limited to **inside** the blue force field.

Any suggestions on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

[image: Gradient in question]
[image: Antoher sample]

Comment: i dont see any radial gradient on your picture, i only  see linear, purple gradient on the left side

Comment: yes, the picture only seems to have a linear gradient but the are other samples that are clearly radial. If there is a way to accomplish what I want with a linear gradient i would be happy to hear.

Comment: ok so what "blue field"` do you mean? can you just show the gradient you want to draw (and not some car with some shadow around it)?

Comment: It is the purple gradient you see in the image, however it has to be drawn on any edge (or part of an edge) of the "blue shadow" around the car.

Comment: seems you have to wait for someone else as i dont get what you really want to achieve

Comment: I added another image